# How to change the format of on array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var res = {
  "status": true,
  "message": "Success",
  "data": {
    "structure": {
      "tables": {
        "ctrM_SETUP_UOM": "([Value_Member], [Display_Member],[Enum_Group])"
      },
      "otherSQL": null
    },
    "data": {
      "inserts": {
        "ctrM_SETUP_UOM": [{
            "value_Member": 1,
            "display_Member": "MT",
            "enum_Group": null
          },
          {
            "value_Member": 2,
            "display_Member": "BBL",
            "enum_Group": null
          },
          {
            "value_Member": 3,
            "display_Member": "TOZ",
            "enum_Group": null
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

let array = [];
array.push(res.data.data.inserts);
console.log(array)
console.log(array["ctrM_SETUP_UOM"]) //need to return the object
```

I am looping and pushing an object into an array.

I want to get rid of the outer indexs of the array so that my array would be like

```
[{
    ctrM_SETUP_UOM:[1,2,3]
},
{
    ctrM_SETUP_COMMODITY:[1,2,3]
}]
```

I have tried it using

```
var arr = [];

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(item) {
  arr.push(obj[item]);
})

console.log(arr);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Current Output -

```
[
    {
        "ctrM_SETUP_UOM": [
            {
                "value_Member": 1,
                "display_Member": "MT",
                "enum_Group": null
            },
            {
                "value_Member": 2,
                "display_Member": "BBL",
                "enum_Group": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ctrM_SETUP_COMMODITY": [
            {
                "value_Member": 1,
                "display_Member": "Aluminium",
                "enum_Group": null
            },
            {
                "value_Member": 2,
                "display_Member": "Crude Oil",
                "enum_Group": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Expected Output -

```
{
    "ctrM_SETUP_UOM":[
        {
            "value_Member": 1,
            "display_Member": "MT",
            "enum_Group": null
        },
        {
            "value_Member": 2,
            "display_Member": "BBL",
            "enum_Group": null
        }
    ],
    "ctrM_SETUP_COMMODITY": [
        {
            "value_Member": 1,
            "display_Member": "Aluminium",
            "enum_Group": null
        },
        {
            "value_Member": 2,
            "display_Member": "Crude Oil",
            "enum_Group": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have updated my code with the current output and the expected output.
Currently if I want to access the "ctrM_SETUP_UOM" with `myarray["ctrM_SETUP_UOM"]` it returns an undefined value. I need to format the array so that it returns the value when I am accessing it with `myarray["ctrM_SETUP_UOM"]`

Comment: When you write `ctrM_SETUP_UOM:1,2,3`, do you mean: `ctrM_SETUP_UOM: [1, 2, 3]` ?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that, I have fixed it in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor. Please post CODE and OBJECTS not pictures of them

Comment: Those are just array indices...

Comment: It's really unclear, please provide better example on what you want to achieve

Comment: Thats just chrome dev tools format to show how array looks like. You can try `console.log(arr.toString()); ` if you are confused with how chrome is displaying this in console.

Comment: I have updated my question and made it more descriptive.

Comment: Please post INPUT too!!! click [edit] then `[<>]` snippet editor and make aa [mcve]

Comment: @mplungjan I have added the code snippet

Comment: @3limin4t0r ... a more straightforward solution would use a [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#syntax) based approach ... something similar to this ... `arr.reduce((result, item) => Object.assign(result, item), {})`